# building Visual studio solution on jenkins through msbuild giving CL error MSB6006

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to build a Visual Studio VC++ solution/project on jenkins build server through batch script that uses msbuild.
The script runs on my system( Win &, Visual Studio 2012 enterprise), without problems.
In the jenkins server , the batch script ran into following problems:

1)It was searching for

```
C:/Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props
```

and hence build would fail.
I created `VCTargetsPath` key with value `(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\` under registry setting

```
 HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0
```

on Jenkins machine and then it would search correctly under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110
```

and the error was gone.
2) CL.exe could not be located on Jenkins.
Added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin`
 to   system env Variable "PATH"  and the error was gone.

3) Now, finally I am getting following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(347,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741701
```

Is there a way to get more information about the error? or any other solution?
I also got information from colleague that adding  `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110` to Jenkins causes known bug in Jenkins, and I don't know that the subsequent build error is due to that or something else?

Note: What is even more confusing is that running the same batchscript from command prompt on Jenkins executes without any such issues but doing it from within Jenkins build server IDE/framework causes issues.
Thanks
sedy

Answer (score 0):

installing full Visual Studio on the server solved the problem. The issue was that server did not have 64 bit version of VS installed and so won't build that.

sedy